# Any negative side effects of using symlinks in your PATH?

Tags: unix, path, filesystems, environment-variables, symlink

I'm curious, do you have any *technical* recommendations against referencing a **symlinked** directory in your PATH environment variable? I.e. as opposed to using the directory that the symlink resolves to?

Answer (score 2):

This will work. It might be slightly slower perhaps.

The Destination of the Symlink needs to start with '/' - e.g. not be relative, because that wouldn't make much sense (because you need to resolve the path from within any directory, and a relative path wouldn't work).

e.g. if you have /data/bin in your PATH, and '/data/bin' is a absolute symlink to some other bin directory, such as '/usr/local/bin' , then this should work.  The destination needs to start with '/'

Comment: So, if I have an original ("physical") directory here: /Users/hced/Dropbox/Code/bin …and I have a file that symlinks to the original directory here: ~/bin …and setting up PATH environment like this: export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH …should be all fine?

Comment: Sorry if above came out a bit complicated (you don't have to evaluate this, I'll just try it and see if it works). What I was curious about in my question, was mainly (apart from whether it works or not) matters of security, bug-prone?, possible incompabilities in certain scenarios, etc.